# Apex Query Exception

Tags: salesforce, apex

I'm encountering an issue in production where the following exception is being thrown:

```
System.QueryException: Non-selective query against large object type (more than 1000000 rows). Consider an indexed filter...
```

The problematic line of code is within a trigger handler class:

```
for (Order_Line_Item__c oli : [SELECT id, Product_Code__c, Stock_Location__c, Contract_Product__r.Product__c FROM Order_Line_Item__c WHERE Contract_Product__c IN :cpIDSet AND Stock_Location__c IN :stockLocationSet AND Status__c = 'Open'])
```

I've tried a few things:

- Made the query more selective using indexed filters.
- Checked if the number of records returned by the query exceeds governor limits (they don't).
- Investigated potential lookup data skew issues, but the number of lookups per object is well below 10,000.

Questions:

- Does anything strike you as an obvious issue?
- How would you make this query more selective?
- Are there additional considerations or approaches I should explore to resolve this issue?

Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Image of System Exception when it first occured:
[image: Exception]

Answer (score 1):

Are they real lookup fields or formulas? Lookups/master-details should be automatically indexed and there wouldn't be much you can do on top of that.

What's passed as bind variables? Some genuine values or nulls? If you run matching query over normal API (without bind variables, real `WHERE Contract_Product__c IN ('a01...', 'a01...')` - how many rows do you get. Bonus points if you know how to use [Query Plan](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386864&language=en_US&type=1)

Is the class marked `with sharing`? Any other filters you can add to the query? Offload it to async operation (@future, queueable or even batch job?)

Comment: These are all fantastic things to start investigating. Thank you for taking time to answer my question.